# Deixar o autocomplete relativo ao textarea quando este aumentar de tamanho

Tags: jquery, html5, jquery-ui

Preciso fazer com que o autocomplete acompanhe o textarea quando este for aumentado.

```
<form class="form-control form-inline">
     <label for="tags" class="control-label" id="upBody">Component: </label>
     <textarea id="tags" ng-model="components"
         class="search ng-pristine ng-touched ui-widget"
         placeholder="Insert a component" autocomplete="on">
     </textarea>
     <button ng-click="search(components)"
         class="btn btn-primary">See objects
     </button>
</form>

.autocomplete({
    appendTo: "#upBody",
    minLength: 0,
    source: function( request, response ) {
      response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
        availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
    },
    focus: function() {
      return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      var terms = split( this.value );
      terms.pop();
      terms.push( ui.item.value );
      terms.push( "" );
      this.value = terms.join( ", " );
      return false;
    }
  });

.ui-autocomplete {
     position: relative;
     overflow-y: auto;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     max-height: 150px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um `event handler mousemove` movendo para *cima*/*baixo* o elemento da lista de acordo com o tamanho do `textarea`, e ao mesmo tempo ajustando a largura:

```
$("#tags").on("mousemove", function(){
   $("#ui-id-1").css({
      "top": $(this).outerHeight()+$(this).offset().top +"px",
      "width": $(this).outerWidth() +"px"
   });
});
```

**Veja exemplo:**

```js
var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
$("#tags")
.on( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      })
.autocomplete({
   appendTo: "#upBody",
    minLength: 0,
    source: function( request, response ) {
      response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
        availableTags, extractLast( request.term )) );
    },
    focus: function() {
      return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      var terms = split( this.value );
      terms.pop();
      terms.push( ui.item.value );
      terms.push( "" );
      this.value = terms.join( ", " );
      return false;
    }
  });

function split( val ) {
      return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
      return split( term ).pop();
    }

$("#tags").on("mousemove", function(){
   $("#ui-id-1").css({
      "top": $(this).outerHeight()+$(this).offset().top +"px",
      "width": $(this).outerWidth() +"px"
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-control form-inline">
     <label for="tags" class="control-label" id="upBody">Component: </label>
     <textarea id="tags" ng-model="components" class="search ng-pristine ng-touched ui-widget" placeholder="Insert a component" autocomplete="on"></textarea>
     <button ng-click="search(components)"
         class="btn btn-primary">See objects
     </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Agradeço a dica, @dvd. Mas no meu caso, eu preciso que quando esticar o textarea, o autocomplete acompanha. Tipo, digito parte de uma palavra, o autocomplete aparece. Quando esticar o textarea,  autocomplete deve acompanhar.

Comment: Esse esticar que eu falo não é ao digitar, mas sim ao maximizar o textarea, com o drag do lado direito, entende?

Comment: Exemplo: O cara digita uma palavra e espera o automplete aparecer, quando aparecer o cara maximiza o textarea com o drag e o autocomplete deve ir junto.

Comment: @AntonioBrazFinizola Ah tah. Coloca o código completo na pergunta para que seja possível reproduzir. Tiver que reproduzir apenas como exemplo e estou vendo que não é igual ao seu.

Comment: Mas meu código é igual ao que vc pôs aí. tirei do mesmo lugar, jquery-ui. A unica coisa que muda são os dados no array.

Comment: Sim, @dvd. Muito obrigado! Agora tenho outra dúvida envolvendo o autocomplete. Quero apenas, por exemplo, informar 3 dos valores do autocomplete. O textfield vai ficar apenas com esse 3 valores informados e não permitirá digitar mais?

Comment: @AntonioBrazFinizola Não seria melhor fazer outra pergunta específica? Aí outros colegas também podem tentar responder.

Comment: @AntonioBrazFinizola Mas se for muito trabalho, eu posso ver aqui pra vc.

Comment: Pode deixar, @dvd. Irei fazer outra pergunta. Vlws.

Comment: Eis aqui a pergunta, @dvd. Desde já obrigado. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/273113/determinar-quantidade-de-itens-do-autocomplete-que-um-textfield-pode-permitir.